# HTML: Forms and Subdomains

Tags: php, forms, post, dns, subdomain

I have a very basic question.  Please consider a site with subdomains:

MAIN SITE: **www.domain.com**

Sub-domain 1: **sub1.domain.com**

Sub-domain 2: **sub2.domain.com**

The main site, in http://www.domain.com/index.php, has a form:

```
<form action="http://sub1.domain.com" method="post">
<input type="text" name="userInput">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Will the data be posted to http://sub1.domain.com and be accessible by the following: (?)

```
<?php 
  $input = $_POST['input']
  //the goal is to make $input, a variable in http://sub1.domain.com/index.php
  //equal to what the user submitted in the form at http://www.domain.com/index.php
?>
```

I simply need to load `sub1.domain.com/index.php` with the posted variables present, no real-time fanciness.  From my reading, I've determined there may be a setting which blocks this activity in apache or some other application, but theoretically, data should be able to be sent to any domain/subdomain from any domain/subdomain using POST, correct?

Comment: Could you link to that reading?  It could be helpful.

Comment: Correct, as long as both domains are accessed over HTTP, a browser will happily POST a form from a page on one domain to somewhere on a different domain.

Comment: Thanks daxelrod for that.  FakeRainBrigand, I did read something about preventing posts from different domains.  As it turns out, what I read actually doesn't say anything about blocking POST requests from Apache, but using the HTTP_REFERER variable in the PHP _SERVER superglobal.  Here's the URL: http://roshanbh.com.np/2008/06/prevent-form-post-request-another-domain.html

Answer (score 0):

**> Step1: Go to Cpanel select Subdomain icon and click on manage

> redirection link of your subdomain. and set redirection to
>   http://sub1.domain.com/xyz.php and save setting
>
> Step 2: Changes in form as below
>
> Step 3: Changed in xyz.php which must be located in inside sub1
>   directory
>
> sub1 | |__xyz.php
>
> xyx.php file
>
> **